# How to pass a LambdaStack down to a PipelineStage with AWS-CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

How would I pass a Stack down to a pipeline stage when using AWS-CDK?

I'm currently trying to create a pipeline which could take a stack as an input.

I've followed the aws-cdk workshop and have a pipeline which self-updates and can deploy a pre-packaged lambda but I'm trying to create a pipeline construct library so that my team can just create a new instance of a pipeline and pass in a later created stack which has relevant roles and event rules added.

My current code is below:

**pipelines-stack.ts**

```
import {
  Stack,
  StackProps,
  pipelines,
  DefaultStackSynthesizer,
  SecretValue,
  aws_codebuild as codebuild,
} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { PipelineStage } from './pipeline-stage';
export type PipelineStackProps = StackProps;

export interface Environment {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly accountNumber: string;
}

export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps,
    environments: Environment[], repoName: string, serviceName: string, lambdaPath: string, policies: Array<string>) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
      deployRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNTID}:role/service-role/ops-codepipeline-role',
    });

    const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      pipelineName: serviceName,
      synth: new pipelines.CodeBuildStep('Synth', {
        input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(`company_repo/${repoName}`, 'main', {
          authentication: SecretValue.secretsManager('github-oauth-token', { jsonField: 'OAUTH_TOKEN' }),
        }),
        buildEnvironment: {
          environmentVariables: {
            NPM_TOKEN: {
              value: '/codepipeline/npm_token',
              type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PARAMETER_STORE,
            },
          },
        },

        commands: [
          'echo "@company:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/" > .npmrc',
          'echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=\\${NPM_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc',
          'npm ci',
          'npm run build',
          'npm test',
          'npx cdk synth',
          'pip install -r lambda/requirements.txt -t lambda',
        ],
      }),
      crossAccountKeys: true,
    });

    for (const environment of environments) {
      const environmentName = environment.name;
      const envAccountNumber = environment.accountNumber;
      pipeline.addStage(
        new PipelineStage(this, environmentName, {
          env: {
            account: envAccountNumber,
            region: 'eu-west-2',
          },
        }, lambdaPath, policies),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**pipeline-stage.ts**

```
import { Stage, StageProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { LambdaStack } from './lambda-stack';
export class PipelineStage extends Stage {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StageProps, lambdaPath: string, policies: Array<string>) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new LambdaStack(this, 'LambdaStack', lambdaPath, policies);
  }
}
```

**lambda-stack.ts**

```
import {
  Stack,
  StackProps,
  aws_lambda as lambda,
  aws_events as events,
  aws_events_targets as targets,
  aws_iam as iam,
} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';


export class LambdaStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, lambdaPath: string, policies: Array<string>, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const role = new iam.Role(this, 'LambdaCleanupRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
    });

    for (const policy of policies) {
      role.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(policy));
    }
    // The code that defines your stack goes here
    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-cleanup', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
      handler: 'app.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(lambdaPath),
      role,
    });

    const rule = new events.Rule(this, 'Schedule Rule', {
      schedule: events.Schedule.expression('rate(1 day)'),
    });

    rule.addTarget(new targets.LambdaFunction(fn));
  }
}
```

Proposed solution is below:

**pipelines-stack.ts**

```
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps,
    environments: Environment[], repoName: string, serviceName: string, lambdaPath: string, policies: Array<string>, lambdaStack: Stack) {
    super(scope, id, props);

// pipeline implementation here

const stage = pipeline.addStage(
        new PipelineStage(this, environmentName, {
          env: {
            account: envAccountNumber,
            region: 'eu-west-2',
          },
        }, lambdaPath, policies, lambdaStack),
      );
```

**pipeline-stage.ts**

```
export class PipelineStage extends Stage {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StageProps, lambdaPath: string, policies: Array<string>, lambdaStack: Stack) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    lambdaStack
  }
}
```

But doing this results in a `The given Stage construct ('Default/BymilesLambdaPipelineStack/dev') should contain at least one Stack` error

The final goal would be for the team to import an npm package from our registry and do something similar to below:

**lambda-deployment-stack.ts**

```
import { LambdaStack } from './lambda-stack.ts'
import { PipelineStack } from '@company-register/cdk-pipeline-python'

const app = new App();

const policies: string[] = [
      'service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole',
      'AWSLambda_FullAccess',
    ];

new PipelineStack(app, 'LambdaCleanupPipeline', {
  env: {
    region: 'eu-west-2',
  },
}, [
  { name: 'Test', accountNumber: '11111111' },
  { name: 'Ops', accountNumber: '22222222' }],
  'bymiles-lambda-cleanup-cdk',
  'bymiles-lambda-cleanup-cdk',
  new LambdaStack(stack, 'BymilesLambdaStack', 'test/test_lambda', policies)
);

app.synth();
```

Comment: Did you remember to [compile your typescript changes to javascript](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/20-create-project/200-watch.html)?

Comment: Yep everything is compiled, it's actually the test suite throwing the error but the implementation is practically the same

Comment: @fedonev I've updated the question with more detail about my current implementation which leads to that error

Comment: The current implementation fails because the stack is not created in the scope of the stage. You need to create the stack in the stage. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - I'm sure we can come up with a solution if you explain it better.

Comment: @gshpychka added more detail about end goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understnding of the proposed solution: implementers should pass a `LambdaStack` to a shared `PipelineStack`. `PipelineStage` is an implementation detail of
the pipeline.

In `lambda-deployment-stack.ts`, implementers pass a function with the signature `(scope: cdk.Stage) => void` to the common `PipelineStack`.
This [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern has two purposes: (1) it defers stack construction until the stage scope is available and (2) it encapsulates the policy and other details of no concern to the pipeline.

```js
// lambda-deployment-stack.ts
// PipelineStack accepts this function signature as a prop
// defers the lambda stack creation until the stage scope is available
const makeLambdaStack = (scope: cdk.Stage): void => {
  new LambdaStack(scope, 'BymilesLambdaStack', 'test/test_lambda', policies);
};
```

Instead of accepting the LambdaStack, policies and paths to the `PipelineStack`, have `PipelineStack` take the wrapper function as a `stackMaker` prop.

```js
// pipeline-stack.ts
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps,
    environments: Environment[], repoName: string, serviceName: string,
    stackMaker: (scope: cdk.Stage) => void) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        // etc...
```

`Pipeline`in turn passes `makeLambdaStack` down to the `PipelineStage`, where the function is called and the Lambda actually constructed.

```js
// pipeline-stage.ts
export class PipelineStage extends Stage {
  constructor(
    scope: Construct,
    id: string,
    props: StageProps,
    stackMaker: (scope: cdk.Stage) => void) {
      super(scope, id, props);
      props.stackMaker(this)  // <- actually call the maker function, in the sceope of the Pipeline Stage
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I get the rough gist with this, where would the initial `makeLambdaStack` function sit? In the `pipeline-stack.ts` file? If so whereabouts, the export makes me think outside of the stack decalaration for `PipelineStack`

Comment: Worked it out, this solved it brilliantly, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help!  I edited the answer to make the role of `lambda-deployment-stack.ts` clearer.